# JSP option tag in foreach only returns first value

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have a form that has a dropdown box and I am using a foreach loop to populate it with values returned from an sql query. It should be returning the index of the loop via the varStatus property. Here's the code:

```
<form action="response.jsp">
    <strong>Select a Department:</strong>
    <select name="depts">
        <c:forEach var="dept" items="${departments.departments}" varStatus="loop">
            <option value="${loop.index}">${dept}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

The dropdown list is being populated correctly, however when submit is pressed, only the first index is being returned, i.e. regardless of which option is selected, only the first value is returned.

The code that receives the returned value is

```
<jsp:setProperty name="department" property="index" value="${param.loop.index}"/>
```

The setter method for index also sets the values of three other variables in the class that are derived from the index if that makes any difference.

Not sure if I've missed something obvious, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `<select>` tag the name parameter that is assigned is the name of the variable that is passed when the form is submitted. This means that in the value field of the `<jsp:setProperty>` tag, this name value should be used as the parameter value, i.e.

```
<jsp:setProperty name="department" property="index" value="${param:depts}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use `.index` it will start counting at 0.

if you use `.count` it will start counting at 1.

I don't see any problem in your code regarding on displaying the output. what is the output that is being displayed anyway?

Comment: '.index' is the correct one to use as the value is used to index into an array containing the names of different departments. The property being set is used to get parameters that are then used in sql queries to find all employees in that department.